# Get Categories based on Product Tag

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

In WooCommerce, I have assigned the Product Tag `Test Tag 1` to numerous products.

I have 5 categories: `Cat1`, `Cat2`, `Cat3`, etc...

Only `Cat2` and `Cat5` have products that have the `Test Tag 1` product tag.

`www.website.com/product-tag/test-tag-1/` displays a list of all the products that have the `Test Tag 1` product tag.

Instead of this product list, is there a way to add in a step which will add in the `Cat2` and `Cat5` categories and then clicking them will show only `Test Tag 1` products in `Cat5`, for example?

Whilst trying I can get this effect to work using only categories and subcategories, however, as I have hundreds of categories it's not feasible to add 5 or 6 (or more) subcategories to each of these cats.

Comment: Why don't you use tag filters on category pages?
`/product-category/cat5/?product_tag=test-tag-1`

Comment: @Yashar That was my original thinking, but its the page above this which is the issue. I'm not sure how to get the page which shows only the `cat2` and `cat5` categories then clicking on one of them shows the tagged products

Comment: you can use a WC filter plugin such as these: [1](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-products-filter/) [2](https://wordpress.org/plugins/themify-wc-product-filter/) [3](https://woocommerce.com/products/product-filters/) to generate custom URLs to filter WC archive pages. And then you can use these URLs to build some custom tag pages based on categories. Note that you can also create these pages without using a third-party plugins, with WC shortcodes. However I can't think of a simple solution for this.